# return accumulated values with Aggregate?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, aggregate

I have a list of Int and would like to 'fold' it like: (((((0+1) + 2) + 3) + 4) +5)
and end up with with a list like the result variable.

```
var numbers = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var sum = numbers.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);  // 15  

var desiredResult = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15];
```

How can I update the Aggregate method to return the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overloads to `Aggregate` all produce a single output an `int`. That's not what you're looking for. You want to project one array to another with a running sum. Something like this would work:

```
var runningSum = 0;
var sum = numbers.Select(i => runningSum += i);

sum = 
[1 3 6 10 15]
```

Comment: There is nothing built-in like this, but there are third party libraries offering this functionality. Check out the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) for example. It includes the [`Scan`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Scan.htm), [`ScanBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ScanBy.htm) and [`ScanRight`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ScanRight.htm) operators.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Thx this is excatly it. Cheers!